# Правильно ли добавлять в сущность посторонние методы в symfony

Tags: php, ооп, symfony, symfony3, best-practice

Изучаю symfony, использую версию 3.4
Возник такой вопрос. У меня есть таблица domains со списком доменов и соответственно сущность для этой таблицы с полями таблицы и геттерами-сеттерами для них.
Появилась необходимость выяснить в коде, есть ли у домена кириллические символы (русские буквы). И возник вопрос, корректно ли будет с точки зрения **best practices** добавить в сущность AppBundle\Entity\Domains метод вроде:

```
public function isCyrillic(){
    return preg_match('/[\p{Cyrillic}]/u', $this->name) === 1 ? true : false;
}
```

А потом добавлять в эту сущность ещё и ещё подобных методов? Или в сущности должны храниться только описания полей таблицы и геттеры-сеттеры для них? А другие методы нужно выносить в сервисы или ещё куда-то?
Интересует ответ именно **best practices**, т.к. хочется писать код корректно и не лепить велосипеды. Нужно мнение профессионала)

Answer (score 1):

Приведенный вами метод вполне укладывается в представление `Enitiy`.
Туда подходит всё что может содержать префикс `is|get|set|has` и прочие.

Сервисы могут иметь подобные методы, но сами они stateless, поэтому придётся на вход подавать эту самую сущность, что не очень практично.

Репозитории так же сам по себе являются stateless, и служат для работы уже с самими сущностями, так что туда тоже не стоит относить подобные методы.

Comment: Проблема в этом подходе (когда метод `isCyrillic` загнали в сущность) заключается в том, что использование подобного же метода для проверки другой сущности приведет к дублированию кода. Поэтому хотя бы в трейт можно эту проверку выделить.

Comment: @u_mulder, методы, как `isCyrillic` весьма специфичны, раньше времени выносить такое - переоптимизация. Трейты для однообразных методов, действительно, отлично подходят. Но к `Entity` плохо применимы из-за отсутствия у свойств типизации на уровне языка.

Comment: @Gedweb а можете чуть развернуть данную проблему ?  Не очень понятна связь подобных методов находящихся в трейтах и типизации свойств в модели. Спасибо.

Comment: @zalex, самый простой пример - значения по умолчанию. Если свойство обозначено в трейте, то значение поменять не удастся.
Ссылаться же на свойство не описанное в трейте через `this` рисковано, т.к. в классе может оказаться дрогой тип поля. Например `string` всесто `int`

Answer (score 0):

Это нарушит принцип [SRP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8). Класс не должен иметь несколько обязанностей. Обязанность данного класс - хранить и получать данные. Метод isCyrillic добавляет классу новую обязанность.
А это может привести к дублированию кода и увеличению сложности класса. Вы не сможете воспользоваться этим методом в других местах или вообще в других проектах.
Поэтому я бы вынес этот метод в отдельный сервис.